# Is it necessary to remount a backend when the vault seals?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I would like to use Hashicorp's Vault with the AWS backend. I've automated the process for unsealing the vault. If the vault were to ever seal, do I have to mount the AWS backend again?

Basically, do mounts get unmounted when the vault seals?

I'm just trying to figure out if I need to add the `mount` command to my unseal automation.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself. I'll post here for anyone else looking.

Backends are not automatically unmounted. In fact, [the documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/#mounting-unmounting-secret-backends) states that umounting a backend destroys all data:

> When a secret backend is unmounted, all of its secrets are revoked (if they support it), and all of the data stored for that backend in the physical storage layer is deleted.

It would be pretty bad if sealing the vault also destroyed all your data. Heh heh.

I was able to test this for myself:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ vault mount aws
Successfully mounted 'aws' at 'aws'!

[vagrant@localhost ~]$ vault mounts
Path        Type       Default TTL  Max TTL  Force No Cache  Replication Behavior  Description
aws/        aws        system       system   false           replicated
secret/     generic    system       system   false           replicated            generic secret storage
sys/        system     n/a          n/a      false           replicated            system endpoints used for control, policy and debugging

[vagrant@localhost ~]$ vault seal
Vault is now sealed.

[vagrant@localhost ~]$ vault unseal
Key (will be hidden):

[vagrant@localhost ~]$ vault mounts
Path        Type       Default TTL  Max TTL  Force No Cache  Replication Behavior  Description
aws/        aws        system       system   false           replicated
secret/     generic    system       system   false           replicated            generic secret storage
sys/        system     n/a          n/a      false           replicated            system endpoints used for control, policy and debugging
```